# How do you deal with mass spam on MediaWiki?

Tags: spam, mediawiki, spam-prevention

What would be the best way to find a users IP address on MediaWiki if all the connections were proxied through squid proxy server and you have access to all user rights?

I am a steward on a centralauth based wiki and we have lots of spam accounts registering and making 1 spam page each.

Can someone please tell me what the best way to mass block them is as I keep on having to block each user individually and lock their accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [configured properly](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/forwarded_for/), your proxy will add the IP address of the user to the [X-Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header of the backend request. If [`$wgSquidServers`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSquidServers) (or [`$wgSquidServersNoPurge`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSquidServersNoPurge)) is properly set, MediaWiki will automatically use that header for all internal purposes except logging (where it would be a performance hit).

For spam-fighting in general, see the list of [antispam extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Spam_management_extensions). [ConfirmEdit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmEdit) (captcha) is a popular choice, [SpamBlacklist](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SpamBlacklist) is also nice. [AbuseFilter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter) was meant more for abusive users, and needs complex configuration, but it is very powerful. For mass-deletion/blocking you can use CentralAuth's `Special:MultiLock` page, [Nuke](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Nuke), [SmiteSpam](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SmiteSpam), I'm sure there are others.

See also [the manual page on combating spam](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Combating_spam).

Comment: Thank you for telling me. Unfortunately, the community stripped me of all my rights but I still know a existing person who can do what I may need to happen and can mass block/lock those users. I'll tell him straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing Extension:Moderation - MediaWiki.
 
This MediaWiki Extension will allow you and your admins to combat spam.